# Missing field in REST GET response while OK in Postman?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I have a WordPress server with custom REST API endpoint to receive statistics.

When tested with Postman(API development environment) I get the following *expected* response:

```
{
    "stats_daily": {
        "referrals_total": "137",
        "intakes_total": "69",
        "families_total": "40",
        "time": "2/26/2019:07:02:23"  /// MISSING in application, see below
    },
    "time": "2/26/2019:07:02:23",  /// MISSING in application, see below
    "referrals": [
    ...
    ]
}
```

But in the React web app. The same request results with the following: (console.log)

```
    families: [{…}]
    intakes: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    referrals: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    stats_daily:
       families_total: "22"
       intakes_total: "88"
       referrals_total: "156"
     __proto__: Object
   __proto__: Object
```

The PROBLEM:
It was the same until I added additional field called *time*. 
From frustration I added it twice... still the problem is elsewhere.

Somehow it is missing in React App, but can be seen in Postman and in the WordPress relevant Post.
Is there some cache involved?
What might be the reason?
Thanks.

NOTE: 
1. The additional data items in console.log output are correct, I just trimmed it from Postman response. Hope its not confusing.
2. No error reported in WordPress server, Nor the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mystery (bug) is simple...

All tests were performed against the *production server* that did not include the change yet.

I am leaving this here in the hope that it will help someone.

But, if for any reason this question should be deleted - I will delete it. Its just a configuration bug.